# Paypal Rest API - Pay with paypal account - leads to error -cookie are not enabled-

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I was curious to try and connect to paypal using MVC code. I tried this tutorial on code project http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/5010108/Re-Error-at-run-time.aspx, but for some reason when I try the pay with paypal account, when I get transferred to paypal sandbox site, I get the message that (cookies are disabled) .. I check my cookies settings although I know they are enabled but just to be sure, I even tried to run the code on different browsers but always the same result.

Seems to be an issue with paypal sandbox to me. Does any one know a work around.

Even the guy who posted the article, is now having the same problem when trying to run the code!

Comment: I can't help with this specific problem, but I've had many issues with the sandbox before!!

Comment: How do you exactly get the message about cookie?

Comment: @MatteoSganzetta The problem got fixed on PayPal sandbox site! .. I wanted to capture an image when suddenly it's working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so others are aware, you can monitor PayPal site issues on the [PayPal Notifications](https://www.paypal-notify.com/eventnotification/search?eventSearchType=PayPalSiteStatus) website, which PayPal keeps updated with known service issues and outages.

The cookie message issue was reported on Feb. 24th as [Issue with Express Checkout](https://www.paypal-notify.com/eventnotification/event_details_popup?eventId=6109) and was resolved on Feb. 25th.

If you're still experiencing this problem, please contact [PayPal Merchant Technical Services](https://ppmts.custhelp.com/).

Answer (score 1):

They got it fixed on PayPal side. It is working fine now.